# Pythons script that joins multiple excel files runs out of memory when writing to disk

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, memory

I wrote a script that joins multiple excel files. Each of these excel files are about 5 megabytes each(There are about 20). Python does not take up a lot of memory up until it writes the joined file to disk quickly shooting up to 2gb of memory and then stopping.

My question here is: Is there a more memory efficient way this can be written?

Entire script:

**concat.py**

```py
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np



excel_path = "C:\\Users\\khernandez\\Desktop\\compare-and-concat\\raw\\"
# File names to join
excel_names = [excel_path + f for f in os.listdir('./raw')]


cols = ['Charges', 'Amount','Taxes','Date','Discount Percent', 'Zipcode', 'Order Number']

# Load them in
excels = []
for name in excel_names:
  print("Loading File: " + name)
  excels.append(pd.ExcelFile(name))
  print("Done!")

print("\n")
# Turn them into dataframes using pandas
frames = []
for index in range(len(excels)):
  print("Converting to data frame...")
  frame = excels[index].parse(excels[index].sheet_names[0],index_col=None)
  frames.append(frame[np.intersect1d(cols, frame.columns)])
  print("Done!")


# Delete the first row of the excel file
print("Removing HEADERS")
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# Combine the dataframes
print("Combining frames")
combined = pd.concat(frames, sort=False)


print("Writing file")  # After about 6 min, script crashes with out of memory error
# Write them out to a file named concated.xlsx
combined.to_excel(excel_path + "concated.xlsx", header=True, index=False)
```

I tried using `gc.collect()` in the for loops but that did nothing.

Comment: How many rows of data are we talking?

Comment: ~22k on each (5-6mb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what the excel files look like it impossible to write an exact solution but you should be able to do everything in one loop. Something like this

```
files=os.listdir(your directory)
concat_data=[]

for f in files:
    xls=pd.ExcelFile(f)
    sheets=xls.sheet_names
    df=pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name=sheets[0],header=False)
    concat_data.append(df)

output=pd.concat(concat_data, sort=False)
output.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```